# Google Drive does not show embedded images anymore

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Since August 7, 2012 Google Drive is not showing images on Documents uploaded by both the Google Drive webpage or by the APIs.

I was using google Docs APIs to upload HTML files referencing public images from the Internet.  The API converts the HTML to a Google Document and displays the images fine.  Suddenly yesterday this behavior is no longer available!  Google Doc will show a gray box (the same size of the image) with a spinning icon.

I realized that is happening even if I upload a Word (.docx) document using the **Upload** feature in Google's Drive website.

Any idea of a workaround?
Thanx,

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue when I upload an image and say convert to google doc format.  It works fine when I don't convert.